# Starting and stopping a minecraft server ran by a bat file using a discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I am using a locally hosted minecraft server for me and few friends to play on. I have been experimenting using a discord bot to listen for a command and then run the bat file starting the server. This has worked. However i have been unable to get it so when the command kill is given in  discord the bot stops the bat/jar file (im not 100% which one it is). For some reason it doesn't appear to register the command. I also cannot restart the server using the start command if the bat file is stopped.

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import subprocess

client = discord.Client()

bot = Bot("!")


@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Server is up!")
    subprocess.call([r'path_to_bat_file'])


@bot.command()
async def kill(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Shutting server down')
    print('stop')

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Your kill command does not seem to be calling anything. What did you try? Also, it would be interesting to see the batch files, to see what they are doing.

Comment: the way to stop the batch file is to type stop in the python shell or cmd window. So my logic was printing stop in the shell might do the same as stopping it. "java -Xmx6G -Xms4G -jar Hexxit.jar nogui
pause" thats the code in the bat file, i have just realised it may be a jar file im trying to stop

Comment: AFAIK, the node.js `print()` command will just print a text on the console; it won't execute it as a shell command. You will probably have to use `subprocess.call()`, or something similar.